# what does [x, y, λ] = xyλ mean in python

Tags: python

I came across the code snippet recently.

```py
def DL (xyλ) :
    [x, y, λ] = xyλ
    return np.array([
            dfdx(x, y) - λ * dgdx(x, y),
            dfdy(x, y) - λ * dgdy(x, y),
            - g(x, y)
        ])
```

However I don't know what `[x, y, λ] = xyλ` means.

Comment: whatever variable `xyλ` contains, this should be expandable into 3 items that will be assigned to the variables `x`, `y`, `λ`. The fact that the right-hand side variable is named `xyλ` is independent from the names of the left-hand side variables.

Comment: The code snippet should have comments, but I think the input `xyλ` is of type list (or some other iterable) and `[x, y, λ] = xyλ` is just assigning the 0,1,2 elements to variables

Comment: I came across this code snippet in a MOOC course, I check the context again, I think you are right, xyλ is a list.

Answer (score 0):

The Python sequence unpacking expression [x, y, λ] = xyλ is used in the code snippet. It is employed to allocate the variables {x}, {y}, and {⁩λ} to the entries in the {xyλ} list. So, if {xyλ} is a list with three values, this line of code assigns those values to the corresponding variables, making it easier to work with them in the subsequent code.